# check if php file exists on server

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to see if a file exists on the local server. I would usually use if function exists but in this case it's not an option.
My question is how can I get number 2 to return true.

1.Returns true:

```
$acf_funcs = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/vac3/acf/page_meta/functions.php';
var_dump(file_exists($acf_funcs));
```

2.Returns false:

```
$acf_funcs = 'http://vac3:8888/wp-content/themes/vac3/acf/page_meta/functions.php';
var_dump(file_exists($acf_funcs));
```

Comment: `file_exists` will only check if the file exists LOCALLY  ...  So unless you had  a `directory` named `http:` it's going to return false .. You need to look for it locally ...  That's why #1 will return true and #2 won't.

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the local server filesystem, you need to get the path component from the URL:

```
var_dump(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . parse_url($acf_funcs, PHP_URL_PATH)));
```

In the above:

```
parse_url($acf_funcs, PHP_URL_PATH)
```

Returns: `/wp-content/themes/vac3/acf/page_meta/functions.php` and pre-pending `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` yields the same as your first example.

This will NOT however check if the file is available via `http://vac3:8888`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `file_exists`  --  You'll need to use `get_headers`

```
$headers = get_headers('http://vac3:8888/wp-content/themes/vac3/acf/page_meta/functions.php', 1);
$file_found = stristr($headers[0], '200');
```